# Pyinstaller --splash option not doing anything

Tags: python, pyinstaller, splash-screen

I have an app that I have been packaging with Pyinstaller. Everything was working perfectly but when I added the option `--splash IMAGENAME.png` no splash screen appeared. I'm running the following command in the terminal in order to compile the app: `pyinstaller --splash sps.png -F main_gui_ver.spec`

My .spec file is as follows:

```py
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\IRDGFRM\\OneDrive-Deere&Co\\OneDrive - Deere & Co\\Documents\\Python Projects\\Bot Creacion de Pedidos'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\IRDGFRM\\OneDrive-Deere&Co\\OneDrive - Deere & Co\\Documents\\Python Projects\\Bot Creacion de Pedidos\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\ttkbootstrap', 'ttkbootstrap'),],
             hiddenimports=['ttkbootstrap', 'importlib.resources', 'PIL.ImageFont', 'tkinter.font', 'openpyxl', 'pymssql'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='AutomatizacionSAP v3.3',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None,
          icon='Resources/application.ico')
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I found you need to specify the `--splash IMAGE_FILE` during the `.spec` file creation. It doesn't work if you simply add the `--splash` option to the pyinstaller command for a spec file previously created without the option.
I found this also to be the case for the `-F` or `--onefile` option.

Be sure to include the path to the image file if it's not located in the same directory as the resultant `.spec` file and then try creating the `.spec` file with:

`pyi-makespec --splash sps.png -F main_gui_ver.spec`

You should see an additional block in the .spec file relating to the splash, and then you can compile with your original command: `pyinstaller --splash sps.png -F main_gui_ver.spec`

See the docs for more info:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#the-splash-target